# Using C# Datetime in an SQL WHERE clause

Tags: c#, .net, sql

How does one convert a C# Datetime into the equivalent SQL DATE type, so that I can do a simple equality in a WHERE clase, with no parametisation?

Comment: Why don't you want to use parameters for that?

Comment: SQL parameters are safer and provide strong typing which can prevent a lot of typing errors in SQL queries. There's really not a good reason not to use them.

Comment: @Raubi, internal batch job and I have been told not to bother....

Comment: By the time you have written this question, waited for the answer and understood it you could have used a parameter many times over.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply convert it to a iso string.

**Date and Time**

```
YourDateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH\:mm\:ss.fffffffzzz");
```

**Only Date**

```
YourDateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

But i really encourage you to use parameterized queries **because you will generate a new Sql Execution plan everytime your T-SQL query is different**.

If you use Parameters you will get only one plan. This results in better performance.

#### More Information

- [Parameterized Queries and Performance](http://codebetter.com/davidhayden/2006/01/05/parameterized-queries-and-performance/)

Answer (score 2):

```
yourDateTime.toString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

But using parameters would be better

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about `SqlDateTime` structure you can use its constructor which accepts a value of `DateTime`  type:

See MSDN: [SqlDateTime Constructor (DateTime)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cxsk2s5e%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I think other answers didn't really understand your question (or I didn't)

From what I gathered you're asking how to convert from C# `DateTime` to SQLs `Date` type (not sql datetime!). All other answers included time in their answer.

If that's true, you don't have to worry about it at all. SQL `Date` is fully compatible with .NETs `DateTime` so just passing it to procedure will strip the time part and pass the date correctly.